# JS files built from typescript stops working if ran independently but not if ran from dist folder

Tags: node.js, typescript, discord.js, tsc

So, this is a weird one but I'll try to explain. I have a typescript project (a discord.js bot to be exact). And I would like to have a dockerfile that builds and then runs said project.

I ended up with the following dockerfile, inspired by [this post](https://simplernerd.com/docker-typescript-production/):

```
FROM node:16 AS builder

WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY package.json yarn.lock ./
RUN yarn install --frozen-lockfile
COPY . .
RUN yarn build

FROM node:16 AS production-prepare

WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY --from=builder /usr/src/app/package.json /usr/src/app/yarn.lock ./
COPY --from=builder /usr/src/app/dist ./
RUN yarn install --production --frozen-lockfile

FROM gcr.io/distroless/nodejs:16
WORKDIR /app/src/app
COPY --from=production-prepare /usr/src/app ./

#This is correct for googles distroless image
CMD ["index.js"]
```

Now to me this should work, we build the typescript files to JS. We make sure we only have the required (production) packages, and we run it in a distroless image.

Now, the bot starts. However, it does not work correctly, certain commands do not function and some seemingly do, I haven't quite figured out why.

So I tried to debug this by doing a the same flow that the dockerfile does (as close as I can) by copying files and running the same command. So I copied the `package.json` and `yarn.lock` file to a new folder and ran `yarn install --frozen-lockfile`. I copied everything else (bar `node_modules`, TS `dist` folder, and my `.env` as those are in my `.dockerignore`) and ran `yarn build` (which is `tsc --build`).

I then made a second folder, copied the `package.json` and `yarn.lock` files from the first folder to there, copied everything from the first folders `dist` to there, and ran `yarn install --production --frozen-lockfile` and then tried doing `node index.js`.

Same result, the bot technically starts but doesn't work properly. However, if I go to the first folder and run `node dist/index.js` it does work properly! The only difference in packages is `typescript` and `@types/glob` (those are my only devDependencies).

So somewhere between running build with the original TS files, and moving the built JS files away, something breaks. And I am completely out of luck when it comes to figuring out what.

Comment: Can you show your package.json? If you didn't create a script for "node dist/index.js" then you won't be able to just run "index.js" as it doesn't exist in root.  Alternatively you could update your CMD command to include "dist".

Comment: @Matriarx that is the way to run googles distroless image, see [their example](https://github.com/GoogleContainerTools/distroless/blob/main/examples/nodejs/Dockerfile)

Comment: When you say "techincally runs but doesn't work properly"? What do you mean exactly? The errors/behaviour might be telling of what the issue may be

Comment: @apokryfos Yea admittedly that is a very bad explanation. What I mean is that the bot does indeed run, I get my little "Bot is ready" console log and no errors and the bot account lights up as online in discord. However, the bot doesn't respond to command/interactions from discord. With the exception of two commands that use straight messages in DM to the bot (instead of the new slash commands/interactions). One of the two DM commands works fine, the other sends a response back (acknowledging the command was recieved) but then does nothing else. Which is why I am so confused about this.

Comment: Maybe just do `COPY --from=builder /usr/src/app/dist ./dist` in that step and then `WORKDIR /app/src/app/dist` to see if that works. If it does then something from the code or dependencies uses specific paths that are determined when it's installed and may cause issues when it's moved